# Return different type of arrays contents from a function

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have a function that I would like to return different types of arrays. Here's what I have so far.

```
func typeForSection(section: Int) -> Array<What do I put here?> {
    switch section {
    case 1:
        return media // media is an array of strings
    case 2:
        return hashtags // hashtags is an array of strings
    case 3:
        return urls // hashtags is an array of NSUrls
    case 4:
        return mentions // array of integers
    }
}
```

What do I need to do to assign for the return array as any type? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `AnyObject` for returning any type of object

```
func typeForSection(section: Int) -> AnyObject
```

`AnyObject` in swift is equivalent to `id` in Obj C

And if you only want to return `Array` with different Object in it use  `Array<AnyObject>`

### Example

```
func typeForSection(section: Int) -> Array<AnyObject>
```